# JFrame maximized to screen size with Dimension

Tags: java, swing, jframe, fullscreen, dimension

All I can think is that I'm not setting the screen size correctly.  Logs show that the height and width look correct.  From the [Swing trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/start/HelloWorldSwingProject/src/start/HelloWorldSwing.java):

```
package net.bounceme.dur.nntp.swing;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HelloWorldSwing {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HelloWorldSwing.class.getName());

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloWorldSwing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


       // Container c = frame.getContentPane();
//        frame.getContentPane();
      //  c.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        // adjust to need.
        Dimension d = new Dimension(400, 40);
        //c.setPreferredSize(d);

        //Add the ubiquitous "Hello World" label.
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello World");
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);

        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        int height = screenSize.height - 50;
        int width = screenSize.width - 50;
        frame.setSize(height, width);
        frame.setSize(d);
        LOG.info(height + "\t\t\t" + width);
        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

obligatory legal boilerplate:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 

/**
 * This example, like all Swing examples, exists in a package:
 * in this case, the "start" package.
 * If you are using an IDE, such as NetBeans, this should work 
 * seamlessly.  If you are compiling and running the examples
 * from the command-line, this may be confusing if you aren't
 * used to using named packages.  In most cases,
 * the quick and dirty solution is to delete or comment out
 * the "package" line from all the source files and the code
 * should work as expected.  For an explanation of how to
 * use the Swing examples as-is from the command line, see
 * http://docs.oracle.com/javase/javatutorials/tutorial/uiswing/start/compile.html#package
 */
```

screenshot:

[image]

Comment: yes, I set the size twice.  I've tried both, neither get me a larger JFrame.

Comment: How is your JFrame looking? Not enveloping the whole screen?

Comment: no, it's tiny:  www.zimagez.com/zimage/screenshot-03282013-013904am.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try removing `frame.pack();`. This gives expanded frame. This is because pack() causes the frame to be [re-sized](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack%28%29).

Comment: @Thufir: Don't _remove_ `pack()`; do it _before_ resizing the frame. Also consider `setExtendedState()`.

Comment: @trashgod You are right, this works event if `pack()` is moved before resizing.

Comment: @Apurv: Right, but other components in the containment hierarchy may need to be packed.

Answer (score 2):

1. `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()` doesn't take into consideration any additional insets of things like the task/dock bar
2. You're calling `JFrame#pack`, which is going to resize the frame to the preferred size of its contents

You should be using `JFrame#setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)`

Comment: I'll take another look later, but I don't seem to have JFrame.setExtendedSize()  ...?  Error on my end?

Comment: Yep, should be setExtendedState

Answer (score 1):

You should comment this line in your code:

```
//frame.setSize(d);
```

Also remove this line:

```
//frame.pack();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `pack()` call. And try setting all three methods being `setSize()`, `setPrefferredSize()` and `setMaximumSize()` with the same dimension.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one ,

```
this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to note for those just finding this,

`frame.setSize(height, width);`

Is backwards, it should have been:

`frame.setSize(width, height);`

Otherwise you will quickly notice when you run the program (unless you have a square screen) your JFrame won't cover part of the right side of your screen.

Also, remove this part of the code to see the JFrame attempt to take up most of the screen (I get most of my screen on a 28" monitor with the above code (without `frame.pack()`):

`frame.setSize(d);`

The above snippet of code is changing you JFrame to the width 400, height 40 that was defined in Dimension d.